# GUI and ssh stop working after some time on Ubuntu 20.04 VM

Tags: permissions, ssh, virtualbox

My account goes to inactive or permissions are being changed, since just after boot I can log in via GUI, then open multiple ssh connections simultaneously, but after a while neither gui nor ssh doesn't work. I also cannot run `sudo` anymore until next reboot.

Do you have any idea what's going on or how to debug? There's nothing in journal logs.

I'm working on Ubuntu 20.04 installed in VirtualBox (Win 10 is the host).

Comment: Things don't "just happen", so there is bound to be a reason for it. If you do not see anything in `/var/log/syslog`, then you'll need to check some of the other files in `/var/log` to see what process might be changing the permissions or – more likely – check the `.bash_history` file in your home directory to see what commands were executed that might have adverse effects.

Answer (score 0):

It was improper configuration of vbox with bridged connection + NetworkManager which was restoring DNS configuration to wrong one.

Logs:

```
Jan 12 09:47:49 AMDN4637VMO1 NetworkManager[479]: <info> [1641977269.8767] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (enp0s8) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
```

`nmcli` output:

```
enp0s3: connected to Wired connection 1
        "Intel 82540EM"
enp0s8: connected to SRPOL
        "Intel 82540EM"
```

The following command resolved the issue:

```
nmcli con mod Wired\ connection\ 1 ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes
```